# Connect Magento to Business Management Software via soap

Tags: magento-1.9

I am looking to link Magento to our in-house Business Management Software (Inventory, Financials, Customer Accounts etc). I would like both systems to talk to each other. I know our Business Management Software has a Soap service that allows for this type of integration. I need our system to update after an order has been placed on Magento. I would need it to the customer account (if it's a new customer), create an order and post a payment (receipt) to the customer's account.

I don't really think it would be important to do it after every order but could probably set up a cron to check for new orders every 15/30 minutes and do it then?

How difficult would it be to achieve this? Would it be expensive?

Answer (score 3):

Magento comes per default with a SOAP API (SOAP v1, SOAPv 2, SOAP v2 with WS-I).

There are various methods for retrieving order and customer details:

To retrieve a list of new orders (for example) after a certain date, you can use [salesOrderList](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.list.html) and afterwards [salesOrderInfo](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.info.html) to retrieve specific order details.

For the customers it's the same: Retrieve a list of customers with the `list` method, and then get specific customer details with the `info` method.

All you have to do is to set up a SOAP API user and SOAP API role which is used to access this data.

> How difficult would it be to achieve this?

Using the standard methods like mentioned above is pretty straight forward. From experience I know most of the time is spent debugging why a specific SOAP call does not work which is mostly a server issue.

> Would it be expensive?

As I don't know how your Business Management Software is able to connect via SOAP: no idea.